# How to get the value of a JavaScript variable same in all the functions

Tags: javascript, html

Following is a piece of code to simulate the login and log out action. ( Just simulation - there is a seperate function for login , which makes value of variable `login` as true. if I click the home button the alert box shows true value as expected. Next if i click `contact` which calls the function `loginCheck` the alert box displays undefined value. Is it possible to keep the value as `true` itself ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var login;
 function logout() 
   {

       login = false;

   }
   function loginCheck() {
   alert(login)

       if (!login) 
       {
           alert("Log In to continue operations");
           return false;
       }
   }

   function loginAction() 
   {

       login = true;
       alert(login);


       }
<script>
```

the html code is:

```
     <li><a href="HomePage.html" onclick="loginAction();">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="return loginCheck();">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.aspx" onclick=" return loginCheck();"> Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="HomePage.html" onclick="return logout();">Log Out</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't maintain state across page reloads. You need to do so yourself. Typically you'd use cookies for this.

There is no value in finding a way for your JavaScript boolean to retain it's value across page reloads, as the various solutions to that problem and the solution to maintaining a user's authorization state are more or less unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep state on the page by using a Singleton class pattern like I wrote below. This solves the problem as you posed it.

However, as meagar wrote in another comment, you cannot use javascript to maintain state across page loads. Authentication/Authorization are normally done on the server side and use cookies to maintain state.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auth = new function() {
        this.logged = false;
        this.login = function () {
            this.logged = true;
        };
        this.logout = function() {
            this.logged = false;    
        };
        this.loginCheck = function() {
            if (this.logged) {
                alert('Logged in!');
            } else {
                alert('logged out!');   
            }   
        };
    } 
</script>

<li><a href="#" onclick="auth.login();">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="auth.logout();">Logout</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="auth.loginCheck();">Check</a></li>
```

More on javacript classes: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to keep state across pages using client-side technologies, such as POST/GET params, cookies, `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`. However, keep in mind that client-side code should never be relied on to enforce security since anyone can tamper with the client-side code, including the data you stored in any of these mentionned storage technologies.